# Extracting data from an array using SQL query

Tags: sql, amazon-s3

I have a field in Athena which looks like this:

```
{ clientip=66.249.69.121, country=US, headers=[{name=Host, value=play.hubhopper.com}, {name=Connection, value=keep-alive}, {name=Accept, value=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8}, {name=From, value=googlebot(at)googlebot.com}, {name=User-Agent, value=Googlebot-Video/1.0}, {name=Accept-Encoding, value=gzip, deflate, br}], uri=/b3219e23cb94459d30487d5caca0be06.mp3, args=s=hh-rss-feed, httpversion=HTTP/1.1, httpmethod=GET, requestid=Md_hWt8b0cpIA_9Id2X3-cqaI1AAVSSk0_YTfZcodwInTfqUp9T_nA==}
```

There are many records like this with various user-agents. I want to fetch data where user-agent = 'Googlebot-Video/1.0'. What should the query be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '.*\{name=User-Agent, value=(.*?)\}.*', '\1') AS user_agent
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that if `\1` does not work as the replacement, you might have to use `$1` instead.  Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OvTqhZ/1) showing that the replacement logic is working.

Comment: It is giving me the following error: 'Unexpected parameters (row("clientip" varchar,"country" varchar,"headers" array(row("name" varchar,"value" varchar)),"uri" varchar,"args" varchar,"httpversion" varchar,"httpmethod" varchar,"requestid" varchar), varchar(36), varchar(2)) for function regexp_replace. Expected: regexp_replace(varchar(x), JoniRegExp, varchar(y)) , regexp_replace(varchar(x), JoniRegExp) , regexp_replace(varchar, JoniRegExp, function(array(varchar),varchar(x)))'